# how to remove multiple picker from the view.window

Tags: ios, uipickerview

In my app on button click i have add pickerview to the windows below is the code show that

```
- (IBAction)btnMake:(id)sender
{
     pickerViewMake = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
        pickerViewMake.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
        pickerViewMake.dataSource = self;
        pickerViewMake.delegate = self;
        [pickerViewMake setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [viewPicker addSubview:pickerViewMake];


        [self.view.window addSubview:pickerViewMake];
    }

-(void)removeAllPicker
{   
    [pickerViewMake removeFromSuperview];
    [pickerViewModel removeFromSuperview];
    [pickerViewYear removeFromSuperview];
    [pickerViewTrim removeFromSuperview];
}
```

remove all picker is the method used for removing the picker from superview 
it works
The problem is that on multiple clicking btnMake number of the picker view cones up then
removeallPicker method call than also pickerview does not remove from superview.

Comment: From the code it seems that you add the pickerViewMake twice and in different views, Why?? I can't understand that. And in removeAllPicker method you remove them from SuperView for once only. May this is your problem

Comment: Why are you adding pickerview in two separate views?

Answer (score 0):

Do one Thing create one **BOOL** variable and set in **viewdidload** yes and check in function if it is yes then picker come and also make it no in **btnmake** method.

Comment: their is no other way to remove multiple picker by creating for loop.

Comment: this is the easiest method.

Comment: but i haved four picker user can click picker mltiple time mean user will select year than they can be changed it.

Comment: So change the value of in picker or create diff-2 picker.

Answer (score 0):

Try in the following way

```
if (<instance>) 
    {
        [<instance> removeFromSuperview],<instance> = nil;
    }
```

After this create your picker then it won't create multiple times, it will create only once.

Comment: what is <instance> ?? i am not getting

Comment: for you <instance> will be "pickerViewMake" or "pickerViewModel" etc. That means the instances which you have created for a class.